# Multiple Oracle Instance on a single Oracle Database on Win7

Tags: oracle

I have installed an Oracle DB server on a windows 7 Machine with a single Instance (Single SID). I want to create another instance (SID) under the same oracle database, Can anyone help or guide.

Thanks
Zaheer

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by providing another port number and service id. But 2 oracle DB in windows 7 is seems bad idea.

In addition, Installing two oracle service in windows 7 has it's own complexity.